# Need to update UI when a checkbox is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a situation where is have a Bootstrap 3 based page which has a checkbox on it:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" id=userActive checked>
```

Before I display the form I want to set the correct state based on the value of the field in the database like so:

```
if (ra.active=='Y') {                
        $("#userActive").prop("checked",true);                
} else {                
        $("#userActive").prop("checked",false);                
}
```

The problem is that the UI display of the form is always Checked (as if true). Actually it is always the value of the initial state. If I remove the CHECKED parameter from the HTML then the checkbox UI display will represent UNCHECK regardless of the value.

The actual DOM element is checked or unchecked correctly (which I can verify by posting the form). It is just the UI that is not being displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, here it is working exactly as you describe. Perhaps you have some other code interfering or some special CSS styling on your checkboxes?

```js
//Some setup to mimic your code
var ra = {
  active: 'N'
};


if (ra.active == 'Y') {
  $("#userActive").prop("checked", true);
} else {
  $("#userActive").prop("checked", false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Y" id=userActive checked>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That appears to have been the problem. There was a plugin that was styling all checkboxes.